# I want to Update the Description field

Tags: data-migration, azure-devops-migration-tools

I want to Update some text(like "This work item is migrated from TFS") in the Description field along with the source text. Any one can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Field Map.

Likley the `RegexFieldMap` will do it. Check https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/